# Store loop variable values in single variable in loop

Tags: php, loops

In below, I am displaying the discount using loop `$finaltot` total displays the value the multiple values that multiple values I have to store in variable with there mathematical addition.

suppose its displaying value `10 23 40` so i have to make like `10 + 23 + 40`

so it will display `$finaltot=73`

so how do I do this within loop.

```
<?php
    $product_orignalprice = $this->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $discountedprice=$_item->getPrice(); 
    $todatlsaving=$product_orignalprice-$discountedprice;
    echo $finaltot=$todatlsaving * $this->getQty(); 

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest/simplest way is to keep adding the data to the variable:

The `+=` sign is used to mean equals whatever it was plus the new value - so writing `$var+=$newVar` is the same as writing `$var=$var+$newVar;`

```
<?php
    $product_orignalprice = $this->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $discountedprice=$_item->getPrice(); 
    $todatlsaving=$product_orignalprice-$discountedprice;
    $finaltot+=$todatlsaving * $this->getQty();
    echo $finaltot;
?>
```

You could however use an array inside the loop and at the end of that go through and tally up the prices (along with whatever else you needed to do with the array).

You could write a class and keep the data in there using a public function to keep adding to a property of the class.

In programming, there are normally multitudes of ways to do something. Use the most flexible, the one that is easiest to read for others reading your code or one that is most efficient - depending on what you need to achieve.

Edit: If you write the `echo` statement INSIDE the loop, it will of course show a cumulative total each time the loop runs - in your example it would output `10 23 73`. If you run the loop incrementing the variable and then actually `echo` the final number after the loop you will get what you want.

Comment: do you give me any clue for  loop incrementing for this question

Comment: @SanjayNakate Not sure what you mean here. I am assuming that the code you posted is just the snippet of code from inside a loop you already have to iterate over your database result (or whatever it is you are iterating over)